# Adapters for SSHD 9mm

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd

I recently bought a 7mm SSHD . I wasn't sure if my laptop had a 9mm or 7mm so I bought 7mm just to be safe. Do I have to buy any kind of adapter to place the 7mm SSHD in my laptop?

Answer (score 0):

Generally no you do not. If your laptop has a mounting cage it will mount the same and in the same location and will just work. If your laptop does not have a mounting cage, then you could have an issue.

Sometimes 7mm drives will come with a foam pad. If you do not have a cage, and your original drive is thicker, use this pad between the SSD and the top of the hard drive area.